# Error with using "dynamic" keyword in Silverlight app

Tags: c#, silverlight, dynamic, visual-studio-2010

I get the following error:
"One or more types required to compile a dynamic expression cannot be found. Are you missing references to Microsoft.CSharp.dll and System.Core.dll"

I do have System.Core.dll, do have I to find Microsoft.CSharp somewhere? It wasn't part of the project and it isn't in the references list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Should be at: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v4.0\Libraries\Client\`

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check out [this blog post](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2009/05/24/silverlight-blend-visual-studio-beta-confusion.aspx).  There are some versioning conflicts with Silverlight 4 and VS 2010 RC 1 that might be causing this problem.