# Why does System.Dynamic not work in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, dynamic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Error with using “dynamic” keyword in Silverlight app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394245/error-with-using-dynamic-keyword-in-silverlight-app)

I want to refactor out my animation code and pass in the dynamic type but in Silverlight it doesn't work.

```
 private void Animate(dynamic o)
        {
            double op = (o.Opacity == 1) ? 0 : 1;
            DoubleAnimation da = new DoubleAnimation();
            Duration d = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
            da.Duration = d;
            Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
            Storyboard.SetTarget(da, o);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(da, new PropertyPath("(Opacity)"));
            sb.Duration = d;
            sb.Children.Add(da);
            da.To = op;
            sbid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            LayoutRoot.Resources.Add(sbid, sb);
            sb.Begin(); 

        }
```

I have the System.Dynamic in the using directive and get the following error:

> One or more types required to compile
>   a dynamic expression cannot be found.
>   Are you missing references to
>   Microsoft.CSharp.dll and
>   System.Core.dll?

I tried to reference the System.Dynamic dll to the project and it's not allowed in Silverlight. Any other ideas of casting to the appropriate type?